# Is it possible to keep different ssh login shells a same $DISPLAY number?

Tags: ssh, xorg, display, jupyter

I am running a Jupyter Server on my remote server with `nohup jupyter lab --no-browser --port 1234 $` and use X11 forwarding to access gui programs on the remote server.

But the `$DISPLAY` number of the Jupyter Server is that one of the current shell which the Jupyter Server was launched. For example, `user` login to the remote server through `ssh`, let's call it `user_shell1@remote`, suppose the DISPLAY number is `localhost:10.0`. If the **same** `user` use a second shell to login the remote, then for `user_shell2@remote` the DISPLAY number is `localhost:11.0`, which means the same user at the second shell cannot use Jupyter Server to run GUI programs because the inconsistency of the `$DISPLAY` environment.

Because I am running some quantum chemical programs which need to run for quite a period of time on the server, I don't want to restart the Jupyter Server each time and I want to access the Jupyter Server's GUI both at home and at my office with two PCs.

Here is the output of `xauth list`

```
(base) [user@node01 ~]$ xauth list
node01/unix:15  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  849739cabda5e7e974a5ef9dd448f864
node01/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  6016f581849916680257ef82ff73582e
node01/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  35df3ba83b9cc86654ff324964dc89d0
node01/unix:12  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  4418caa4a79c693da602c37e08202da5
```

Actually the "users" from 10 to 12 are all the same account but access to the remote server at different local machines, is it possible to set all these "users" the $DISPLAY numbers so that these $DISPLAY numbers are consistent to that of the running Jupyter Server.

Or is there any other method to access the GUI capability without restarting the Jupyter Server at different local machines?

Comment: You should just be able to explicitly override the display value, `export DISPLAY=localhost:10`. When you run an X11 program it will lookup this display name in the xauth list, extract the magic cookie and apply it when connecting to the `localhost:10` server. If a user has read access to the `~/.Xauthority` file, then it has access to the display connection.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried to use `export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0`  command to set the env variable manually at a new login shell of which the $DISPLAY is `localhost:11:0`, for example. But it still does not work. As far as I know, it is only possible to work if I set the $DISPLAY to the new `localhost:11.0` in the Jupyter Server through its inner terminal. However, the .ipynb file seems to ignore the new env variables, the command `!echo $DISPLAY` still returns `localhost:10.0` even I reopen this ipython notebook after setting the $DISPLAY to `localhost:11.0`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about Jupyter, so cannot help in that respect. Perhaps an alternative mechanism would be to run a virtual X11 server on the remote, such as Xvnc's vncserver, launch jupyter telling it to use that local server, then later clients can connect to this display with vncviewer.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment, I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @meuh suggested, I post my own answer here.
Magic commands of Jupyter can reset the environment variables of the notebook without restarting the Jupyter server.

So here I just use `%set_env DISPLAY localhost:11.0` to reset the DISPLAY env variable consistent to the current login shell and I can run gui programs in ipython notebook without restarting the Jupyter Server.